# "Interfere in" vs. "interfere with"

Tags: differences, verbs, prepositions, american-english, british-english

I was taught that when *interfere* is followed by *in*, it means *to get involved in something that doesn't concern you*;  when followed by *with*, it means *to prevent something from being done*.  And this is confirmed by British English speakers on the other sources I have read.

However, when I looked up this word in [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/interfere), I just found this entry: 2. to take part in the affairs of others; meddle (**often followed by with  or in** ).

Is this a difference between American English and British English? As an American English speaker, will you also use **interfere + with** (as it says in Dictionary.com) when you are trying to express, for example, "Don't interfere in other people's business"?

Comment: FWIW: I am not a native speaker, but learned English in Boston, MA. I use *with* and *in* interchangeably.

Comment: @F'x How do you pronounce "I park my car in Harvard yard"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the case of, for example, someone else's life, you can either **interfere in** or **with**. The former is critical of *the fact that you meddled at all*. The latter is critical of *the results of your meddling*.

OP's definition of *interfere in* is correct - it means to get involved (usually, in matters that others think don't concern you).

To *interfere with* means to disrupt. Wave patterns, for example, can interfere with each other. This means they are mutually disruptive. Whilst it's true that *interfering in* someone else's affairs *may* be disruptive, it needn't be. But if you *interfere with* their affairs, you're definitely having a bad influence.

There's also the idiomatic usage of a paedophile interfering with a victim, which normally refers specifically to touching a child's genitals. I think in this case the thing being disrupted is the child's (future) sexual identity, but most of us would prefer not to dwell on the exact meaning there.

Comment: The OP specifically asked whether there is a difference in this respect between British and American English. Is your answer meant to imply that, no, there isn't?

Comment: I didn't address that point because I've no idea whether it's even *meaningful*. For example, I know that many BrE speakers associate ***interfere with*** with sexual predation (esp of *minors*). Doubtless that's the same for at least *some* AmE speakers, but I don't know how many.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say "in" and "with" are universally interchangeable in relation to "interfere", but I also don't think I would agree with your defined distinctions.  The difference, at least for me, is the same as with the vagaries of prepositions in general.

As an American, here's how I would interpret these phrases:

"Interfere in someone's business" : to meddle in someone's personal life
"Interfere with someone's business" : to meddle in someone's proprietorship

Answer (score 0):

> ... when interfere is followed by in, it means to get involved in something that doesn't concern you; when followed by with, it means to prevent something from being done.

This is an attempt to create a simplistic rule and is not so.

To interfere **in** [noun phrase], and to interfere **with** [noun phrase] differ adverbially as **in** [noun phrase] and **with** [noun phrase] are adverbial prepositional modifiers.

We can imagine other examples such as "to interfere quickly" and "to interfere unhelpfully"

Any difference therefore occurs because of the nuance of the preposition.

The **in** version is locative (inside/within): the action of interfering is occurring **within** the matter.

The **with** version is contemporaneous: the action of interfering is occurring at the same time that the matter is taking place - it accompanies the matter.

Comment: You're right on "in", but I think "with" is the same as in "play with something": you're acting on or modifying something, and nothing to do with time.

Comment: @StuartF. I considered this but for A to be (or be done) with B, B must be simultaneously present: *He dug the garden with a spade"; *"He was with his wife.*"